# Теги form, input, button - непонятное поведение

Tags: javascript, html, form, события

Суть проблемы: когда инпут и кнопка обернуты в форму, то при нажатии Enter на инпуте, срабатывает событие click на кнопке.
Почему так происходит и как сделать так, чтобы клик на кнопке не срабатывал?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.type, e.target.nodeName)
})



const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Это не в кнопке дело а в форме, всю жизнь у неё такое поведение дефолтное вроде бы

Comment: А если нажать на button - то ожидается что? Что форма засабмиться без участия js или сабмит формы будет обрабатываться через js?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, та не. На клик по кнопке другое поведение. В реальном проекте, кнопка к инпуту, логически вообще, не относиться.  Это же я саму мякотку здесь описал. "Баг" - в чистом виде. Ситуация намного сложнее. Приложение на Vue, c с кучей компонентов

Comment: Добавь `input` с `type="button"` вместо `button` и `onclick` обработчик который будет отправлять форму. Или явно запрети отправку по кей коду `enter`..

Comment: @Rudi, да, это помогает. Пока не знаю, на сколько это у меня применимо - надо думать. Но хоть 1 вариант есть. Спасибо

Comment: Да не за что..)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - решил. Спасибо)

Comment: @Rudi - - решил. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо комментариям, подсказали правильное направление.
Оказалось, что проблему можно решить, если разорвать связь между кнопкой и формой. Для этого кнопке надо установить атрибут `form`, который будет указывать на другую форму. В моем случае, я, вообще, оставил этот атрибут пустым

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.type, e.target.nodeName)
})

const form = document.querySelector('form')
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text">
  <button form="">Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Корректнее было бы указать у кнопки type="button". http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/type

Comment: @ВикторКарев, да, кстати - по итогу так и сделал)